# Can I get offset of the record from start of the file while using Avro

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

In Hadoop when using TextInputFormat we get the offset of each value from the start of the file. Can I get similar offset while using Hadoop with Avro?

I have a file with Avro records and I want to process it with Hadoop. I need some kind of total order on the records. In plain Hadoop I would use the offset for that.

Comment: If the Avro input format doesn't supply it you will probably have to extend it to add that functionality.

Comment: Text files also do not support in but its there built in TextInputFormat in plain Hadoop. It can be easily computed from offset in the current chunk of the file and sizes of earlier chunks. But is it built in Avro? I cannot find that.